# Paths in Node.js

Tags: node.js, apache, .htaccess

I used to use `Apache` + `.htaccess` to serve a `index.html` page in a subdomain. The `.htaccess` redirected every pathname in any subdomain to the `index.html` itself.

For example:

In `http://path1.myserver.com/chat`, `chat` wasn't treated as a path, but as a "parameter" to the `index.html` file.

Also, `http://path2.myserver.com/chat` would be redirected to the same `index.html` file.

When I changed the server to Node, I couldn't (shouldn't) use `.htaccess` anymore.

How can I move from Apache to Node, keeping this functionality?

I tried to use `vhost` + `router`, but unsuccessfully.

I can set `vhosts` to serve `*.myserver.com` to a specific router, so `http://path1.myserver.com` and `http://path2.myserver.com` are correctly redirected to the same `index.html`, but when I try `http://path1.myserver.com/chat`, chat is being treated as a path, giving me a 404 error.

I need to make sure that every pathname in the pattern `*.myserver.com/*/.../*` be served by the same `index.html` (like done in `.htaccess`).

Comment: Show us your node code. By default `http.createServer` listen to a port, hence every url you throw at it.

Comment: Node is listening correctly and the way it is supposed to. If I go `http://path1.myserver.com/chat`, it tries to go to `/chat` folder (it's correct and the default behaviour). But I want to make that every path after `/` be redirected to `index.html`, so that URL `http://path1.myserver.com/chat`, be redirected to `http://path1.myserver.com/`, and `chat` be only a "parameter". I don't have a node code, once I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You're probably mistaken about how Node.js works. You start a node.js program and that program does the routing. Apache would only act as a reverse proxy.